# Simple startup script on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This *should* be easy, because there's a squillion questions about it, but seemingly I'm missing something.  I have a script that creates some directories that I need to run at boot time.  It's way too simple to bother with figuring out upstart or anything -  it's not a service, it doesn't need monitoring, it just needs to run at boot time, with superuser privileges.  I've tried putting the script directly in /etc/rc2.d - it ran once, at one boot, and never again.  Does the system somehow remember it ran and didn't get shut down or whatever?  I've also added a cron job as root and added the script as an @reboot task, still no dice.  This is on an s3 Ubuntu instance - do s3 instances have some bizarre way of booting up that is causing these simple things not to work?

*edit*: I should mention that I need this script to run as early as possible at boot, since among other things it sets up /tmp, which is a bit important to a number of parts of the system.

Comment: Never used S3, but couldn't you just stick it in `rc.local`? Be sure you're using the full path to the script as `$PATH` may not be initialized as you expected.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that will run early enough.  I want to run this script ASAP because one of the things it does is symlink /tmp so it's writable - as you can imagine, not having /tmp makes some things a little unhappy.

Comment: Good to know, you should include that, and any additional requirements, in an edit to your question.

Comment: Ok, I've done it and made this comment of sufficient length.  heh.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no dice' ? What shows up in your logs when no dice happens ?

Comment: Nothing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Place your script to `/etc/rc3.d/`-directory or create a symlink from other location.
2. Name the script or link in `/etc/rc3.d/` to `S50myscript`. (The number influences on the start order, capital S is required.)
3. Make sure that the script has the execute bit in place (`chmod +x script.sh`)
4. Make sure your script includes the interpreter at start, like `#!/bin/sh` if it is a shell script.
5. If needed, you can debug it by placing needed echos to the script, like `echo "step1" >/script.log`, `echo "step2" >>/script.log` etc.

Hopefully this helps :-)

Comment: That worked - the number/start order thing sounds dimly familiar but I had clearly forgotten it years ago.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution if is to add your code to `/etc/rc.local`. Then it is executed as last script.

The *rc.local* is an *old* BSD style startup script that is honoured on most of the linux flavours I know.

If you want a more control other the invocation time in the boot procedure, please have a look at [man update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) for managing the correct set of symlinks from the technical `/etc/rc?.d/` directories to the `/etc/init.d/` directory of your startup scripts. Here you can define the order of the script invocation in the boot process.

PS: My advice for *portable* logging in a startup script is to use the `logger` command. This gives your shell script the ability to send messages to the *syslog* daemon.

PS: **missing LSB informations**

An example of the LSB information for `update-rc.d` is a comment section like this:

```
  ### BEGIN INIT INFO
  # Provides:          tomcat7
  # Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
  # Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
  # Should-Start:      $named
  # Should-Stop:       $named
  # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
  # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
  # Short-Description: Start Tomcat (c42Cfg user instance)
  # Description:       Start the Tomcat servlet engine (c42Cfg user instance).
  ### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: Also, update-rc.d seems to be ill-tempered in ways I don't understand: `update-rc.d -f create_mounts.sh start 2` tells me the script doesn't have LSB information.  I don't *want* to know what LSB information is - it's just a super simple script, remember.

Comment: I would also point out that per my original question, rc.local isn't early enough in the boot process in this case.

Comment: For the LSB information see new PS section above.